# sorting a hashmap by value in xtend

Tags: lambda, hashmap, xtend

Suppose I have a java.util.HashMap object.  I want to produce a List in which the entries in the HashMap are sorted high to low by the value of the Double.  How do I do it?  I've made a stab at it in Java using the Guava Ordering class, but I don't like the aesthetics of jumping from xtend to Java and, besides, it isn't working :(  I have the sense that this should be easy in xtend using lambda expressions, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
val source = newHashMap('one' -> 1.0 , 'two' -> 2.0)
source.entrySet.sortBy[-value]           // List<Map.Entry<String, Double>>
```

or if you only want the keys

```
source.entrySet.sortBy[-value].map[key]  // List<String>
```